# How to find result set from two different date comparisons?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, psql

How to find result set from two different date comparisons

**How to find period1_label_cost, period2_label_cost in this query without using this query ?**

Only period1_label_cost column value is getting

```
 select distinct customers.id as customer_id, customers.first_name as first_name, customers.last_name as last_name, SUM(orders.total_cost) as period1_label_cost

from customers inner join orders
            on customers.id= orders.customer_id

            where
            date(orders.created_at) between 'start_date1' and 'end_date1'

        group by  customers.id , customers.first_name, customers.last_name, customers.preferred
            having(SUM(orders.total_cost) > sales_exceeded
 intersect

        select distinct customers.id as customer_id, customers.first_name as first_name, customers.last_name as last_name,
      customers.preferred as preferred, SUM(orders.total_cost) as period2_label_cost

        from customers inner join orders
        on customers.id= orders.customer_id


        where
            date(orders.created_at) between start_date2 and end_date2


        group by  customers.id , customers.first_name, customers.last_name, customers.preferred
        having( SUM(orders.total_cost) < sales_below) order by first_name asc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for mere joins? Put your two queries in your `FROM` clause and join them on `customer_id`, then join with the `customers` table and show the results.

```
select
  c.id as customer_id, 
  c.first_name, 
  c.last_name,
  c.preferred, 
  period1.label_cost as period1_label_cost,
  period2.label_cost as period2_label_cost
from
(
  select
    customer_id, 
    sum(total_cost) as label_cost
  from orders 
  where date(created_at) between <start_date1> and <end_date1>
  group by customer_id
  having sum(total_cost) > <sales_exceeded>
) period1
join
(
  select
    customer_id, 
    sum(total_cost) as label_cost
  from orders 
  where date(created_at) between <start_date2> and <end_date2>
  group by customer_id
  having sum(total_cost) < <sales_below>
) period2 on period2.customer_id = period1.customer_id
join customers c on c.id = period1.customer_id;
```

Comment: Correct, you saved my day. 
How can i find more record for last order date for each customer from this results of customers, from this query

I need MAX(date(orders.created_at) ) i.e last order date for each customer

Comment: Select `max(date(created_at)) as maxdate` along with the label costs in both subqueries. Then in your select clause add `, max(period1.maxdate, period2.maxdate) as last_order_date`

Comment: This will fetch max of orders created at from those two date different ranges. But if any customer has placed ordered after these two date ranges will not come. How can I gate a last order date for that customer without comparison of dates.
i.e 
if i am searching customer from 1st jan to 1st feb with sales above 100
and order from 25th jan to 25th feb with sales below 2000 .
But incase any customer belong to thses dates and has order another in 7th march that date should  show .

Comment: The last order regardless the given date ranges? You can use a subquery in your select clause: `, (select max(created_at) from orders where customer_id = c.id) as last_order_date`. An alternative would be a subquery in your from clause.